# Error "declared column type INT for column id incompatible with ORC file column type string query" when copy orc to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-redshift, orc

Error "declared column type INT for column id incompatible with ORC file column type string query" when copy orc to Redshift using the command:

```sql
from 's3://' 
iam_role 'role' 
format as orc;
```

Comment: Based on the error message, I'd say that the data type in the file is incompatible with the data type in the table. But since you provide no information other than three irrelevant lines from your copy command, who knows?

Comment: @Parsifal what other information would you like to receive? I can provide it

Comment: Table definition, full copy command, and file content definition. But once you do that, I think you'll see the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when the columns in orc are not in the same order of redshift columns, you can solve this with:

```py
df = df.select('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
```